# how can I connect to an https url with Java?

Tags: java, url, ssl, https

I have tried to connect to an https url using sample Java code I found on the web:

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.InputStream;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.URL;
 import java.security.cert.Certificate;

 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

 public class SSLClientTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        URL hp = new URL("https://godaddy.com");
        //URL hp = new URL("https://127.0.0.1:8443");
            //URL hp = new URL("https://www.google.com/");
        HttpsURLConnection hpCon = (HttpsURLConnection) hp.openConnection(); 

        System.out.println("after connection made:");
        int responseCode = hpCon.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("responseCode:" + responseCode);

        boolean isProxy = hpCon.usingProxy();
        System.out.println("is using proxy:" + isProxy);
        InputStream obj = hpCon.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(obj));

        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("content >>" + s);
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

but get various error messages that I cannot resolve or resolve with any of the many internet posts on these error messages.  How can I connect to an https url, ssl, with Java?

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1902)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:276)
...
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:142)
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:91)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:347)
at 
... 13 more
```

and

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:352)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
... 10 more
...
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:946)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338)
at SSLClientTest.print_https_cert(SSLClientTest.java:56)
at SSLClientTest.main(SSLClientTest.java:21)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:352)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
... 10 more
```

Comment: This link might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17407531/standalone-java-code-to-invoke-wso2-secured-web-service

Comment: not sure how I can use this info

Comment: It's not clear which stack trace belongs to which attempt (since you've commented out some URLs). "*No subject alternative names present*" was certainly produced when you were using an IP address, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8444863/372643).